# Kendo UI time parsing and "Hmm" format

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I'm trying to use the Kendo UI time control and I'm running into problems with the parseFormats option.  I think I've narrowed it down to the Kendo time parsing: the first line of code below returns null when it seems to me it should return 5:00, as the second does.

```
kendo.parseDate('500','Hmm') //  returns null
kendo.parseDate('0500','Hmm') // returns 5:00 as a Date()
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current `parseDate` implementation looks like it tries to take 2 digits, then decides that 50 is too big for the number of hours, then decides it is an invalid date and returns null.

You can try to file a support ticket with Telerik and see if they will fix it, or you can fix it yourself and submit a pull request on GitHub. The project is open-source here: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core